# E: The package oracle-database-xe-21c needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it

Tags: dpkg, oracle

I decided to install Oracle on Ubuntu but in the process of install, I encountered a problem:

`E: The package oracle-database-xe-21c needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.`

After that when I want to install other program on Ubuntu this issue is raised and says:

`E: The package oracle-database-xe-21c needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.`

Now I want to remove all things happened in this process. Can anyone help me?

How I can uninstall or remove everything of Oracle that has been installed incorrectly on Ubuntu?

Comment: Please edit your question and show the steps you took while trying to install Oracle. Also state the version of Ubuntu you are using.

Comment: The easiest, fastest, and simplest way is to simply follow the message and reinstall the package, then apt will let you uninstall it safely and automatically. To force-uninstall the package is possible, but can be unpleasant. You might wind up tediously cleaning up the resulting mess by hand.